# How to determine if Uber services an area?

Tags: uber-api

Is there an way to determine if there are even any uber drivers, or if uber has service, in a particular city?  Aside from getting "no drivers available" which is essentially an empty response set - but that doesnt really let you know "Yes, service exists here, but nothing is available right now"  versus "No, service does not exist here".  Is there a specific message or response code or way to determine this?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use the estimates endpoint and a latitude/longitude to lookup what services are available currently in an area.

Find out more about how to get products and estimates in the getting started guide: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/getting-started

Comment: Originally I pulled `/v1/estimates/time` first...if no ETAs were available then I interpreted that as "no cars/drivers available".  If there were times available then I went onto Products and eventually Price.  According to your response above, I reversed that, and now I am pulling `/v1/products` first...assuming that if Prods are listed for a lat/lng then I move onto ETAs and Pricing.  However, I tested this new method in Austin TX (supposedly where Uber does NOT exist anymore) and Products returned an UberX product (but no times).   So I am still not if your response answers my question.

Comment: Getting an estimate/price for a given product will let you know if the product is actively available in that market.

Comment: This doesn't work.  Best I can tell, `Uber does not service your area` is the same response as `drivers not available`.  All the estimates do is return an empty data set for both situations...which doesn't allow me to differentiate between the two.  Here is a data response for a location in Austin TX (where Uber doesn't service at all): `{times: []}
times : []` , but products IS returning a single prod UberX. I then chose a town with 3 streets in the middle of no where and get exact same results, a single product Uberx response, and an empty time set, seems this is just the default response.

Comment: The products endpoint does not reflect real-time availability of the products. Please use the Time Estimates endpoint to determine real-time availability and ETAs of products.Yes, exactly if there is no estimates available then the product is not available in that market.

Comment: no offense, but I don't think you fully understand the issue.  My original code pulled ETAs first, .and there were plenty of occasions where `/v1/estimates/time` came back empty - and that is in my home town where I know Uber exists.  Thus using ETAs as method to determine if Uber even exists in a town is not effective, because its the same result when Uber does exist in a town but no rides are currently available.  Lyft - on the other hand - actually returns an HTML 400 error response that says "Lyft does not provide service to this area".

Comment: Original code I pulled `/v1/estimates/time` first from Uber. No service and no drivers returned the same response - an empty `{times: []} data set.  Second time I pulled `/v1/products` - and at a minimum it returned a single UberX even though Uber had no service in that cit (I used Austin TX).  I then tried several small middle of no  where towns and products always returned at least one Uber product - even though Uber doesn't have any service in the towns.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I think I understand now. We provide real-time status for products actively available via the eta endpoint, but do not have a clear endpoint to say if uber does not ever provide service to that area. It is currently ambiguous and I will discuss with the team and follow up to if we have a better way.

Comment: Ok...we are on the same page now.  Thank you...I think it is a feature Uber should add.  Knowing the difference will allow me to post a message like "Sorry, currently no drivers are available, please refresh in X minutes" versus "Uber does not provide any services in your area (yet)".  This difference also allows me to program various other things accordingly.